# What data type for a column which can have three states: yes, no, unknown

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, null

I have an application where the user can decide between:

- yes
- no
- unknown

I started to use a boolean column which is nullable.

But things get quite complicated since my framework (django) does not provide a input field for coding a search form out of the box.

In the search form I need four states:

- yes
- no
- unknown
- show all (ignore this column in the search)

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307866/search-form-for-nullbooleanfield

An old rule of thumb comes to my mind again:

> Avoid nullable db columns.

I want to change the data type from a nullable boolean field to something different.

What data type for a column which can have three states: yes, not, unknown?

I use Postgres 9, but AFAIK this should not matter for this question.

Comment: That rule of thumb is one of the worst myths.  NULLs are your friends (if you know them enough).

Comment: @dezso what should I do if the customer wants to add an additional state?

Comment: I don't know why you ask this from me, but then you should opt for an enum or a separate lookup table to store the different states.

Answer (score 7):

You want `boolean`.

It can have `true` (=yes), `false` (=no) and `null` (=unknown)

More details in the manual:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html

---

"*Avoid nullable columns*" is only a recommendation. If you need an "unknown" state, then `NULL` is **exactly** what you are looking for. It was specifically created to represent "unknown".

Postgres even support the keyword `unknown` for boolean expressions: `where some_column is unknown` is equivalent to `where some_column is null` if `some_column` is defined as `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

Does the BIT datatype exist in Postgres land?

BIT is the datatype I use in SQL Server when I want to have Y/N/NULL values only.

Comment: Postgres uses the standard `boolean` data type for this.

Comment: There _is_ a `bit` type, but I never felt the desire in the last ten years to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you can use `models.CharField` with combination with a field option `choices` as it is described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices.

This solutions is more flexible in case when your logic changes.